# Пустой файл после очистки данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, регулярные-выражения, api

Kод:

```
d = str(all_users_details)
b = str(re.findall('(?:"id": )(\d+)', d))
ar = [', ']

for x in ar:
    b = b.replace(x, "|")

    with open ('{{ids{0}}}.json'.format(urlfile), 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
        json.dump(b, outfile, ensure_ascii=False, indent=0)
```

Где:

```
b = str(re.findall('(?:"id": )(\d+)', d))
ar = [', ']
for x in ar:
    b = b.replace(x, "|")
```

Это фильтрация поступающих от `api` данных (которые даются в виде списка), где-то тут закопана ошибка т.к после завершения программы именно этот файл выходит пустым, в то время как нефильтрованный файл цел (в конце я дам часть этого файла).
Если запросите весь код я дам, но именно в этой части ошибка т.к только этот файл пуст

Начало основного файла:

```
[
{
    "id": 982431710,
    "first_name": "Петр",
    "last_name": "Гарин",
    "user": "Engenegar",
    "phone": null,
    "is_bot": false
},
{
    "id": 576352214,
    "first_name": "Товарищ",
    "last_name": "Легасов",
    "user": "moresarcasm",
    "phone": null,
    "is_bot": false
},
{...
```

Весь "очищенный" файл:

```
"[]"
```

Comment: Боже. Зачем парсить json регулярками? Восстановите нормальный объект и работайте с ним.

Comment: какого вида файл вы пытаетесь получить?

Comment: и да, json.load() json.loads()

Comment: @Mrage 000000000|1111111|222222222...

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Говорю же, руки у меня крюки, не нашел я методов фильтрации списков которые бы работали у меня

Comment: Отформатируйте нормально код. Просто копируйте из вашей IDE и вставьте сюда. Над и под кодом тройные апострофы ```. Какой тип имеет `all_users_details`?

Comment: @Mrage В моем коде основной файл может обновляться многократно из-за того, что я получаю данные порциями, ошибок не будет?

Comment: используйте "a" вместо "w", тогда файл не будет постоянно опустошаться

Comment: @Vorobuska, я поправил форматирование кода. Поправьте, если что-то не так (я не уверен, вложен ли у вас блок with в цикл for или нет).

Comment: @insolor Спасибо, думаю все кто сюда заглянет скажет вам "Спасибо"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import json
data = json.loads(all_users_details)
ids = []
for item in data:
    ids.append(item.get("id"))
with open(f"{ids[0]}.json", "w", encoding="utf8") as file:
    json.dump("|".join(ids), file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=0)
```

Не стоит парсить json с помощью регулярных выражений, т.к в модуле json уже есть необходимые для этого инструменты. json.loads преобразует строку json в объект Python, в данном случае в list с dicts в нем. Мы можем итерироваться по листу и получать значения словарей, как из обычного словаря, после преобразования, собирая все id. Так же, я использовал шаблонные строки, вместо метода format, т.к это выглядит более уместно в данной ситуации.

Comment: Интерпретатор ругается что json.loads работает только с строками, а данные даются в виде списка

Comment: @Vorobuska значит опустите момент с json.loads. у вас итак объект python.